What is wrong in my implementation of Ford-Bellman algorithm?
I am trying to solve the following task:
Given a directed weighted graph with edges whose weight can be negative. Find the length of the longest path from the first to the last vertex. If such a path does not exist, output ":(". If such a path is infinitely long, output ":)".
My code works correctly for 21 test cases out of 22. The problem is that I can't pick the tests for which the code is not working correctly. Here is my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int val = 0;
    bool isNull = true;
};

struct Edge
{
    int from;
    int to;
    int cost;
};

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    vector<Node> nodes(n);
    vector<Edge> edges(m);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        int from, to, cost;
        cin >> from >> to >> cost;
        edges[i] = { from - 1, to - 1, cost };
    }
    nodes[0].val = 0;
    nodes[0].isNull = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < max(nodes.size() - 1, (vector<Node>::size_type)1); i++)
    {
        for (auto [from, to, cost] : edges)
        {
            if (!nodes[from].isNull && (nodes[to].isNull || nodes[to].val < nodes[from].val + cost))
            {
                nodes[to].isNull = false;
                nodes[to].val = nodes[from].val + cost;
            }
        }
    }

    if (nodes.back().isNull)
    {
        cout << ":(";
        return 0;
    }

    for (auto [from, to, cost] : edges)
    {
        if (!nodes[from].isNull && nodes[to].val < nodes[from].val + cost)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < max(nodes.size() - 1, (vector<Node>::size_type)1); i++)
            {
                for (auto [from, to, cost] : edges)
                {
                    if (!nodes[from].isNull && nodes[to].val < nodes[from].val + cost)
                    {
                        if (to == nodes.size() - 1)
                        {
                            cout << ":)";
                            return 0;
                        }

                        nodes[to].val = nodes[from].val + cost;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << nodes.back().val;

    return 0;
}

Also I know, that the correct answer for the test that the program failed is ":)", because I tried to send a program, which outputs ":)" in all cases, and it passed this test (but, obviously, did not passed lots of other). That means that the problem is probably in the part of program, which checks when to output ":)".
So the question is: what is wrong in my code?
Edit: it is guaranteed, that 1 <= n <= 2000, 1 <= m <= 10000. Also I have no access to the test cases
Edit: here is an original problem https://www.eolymp.com/uk/problems/1454

Figure out what tests failed and obtain the test data. Then spend some time with your debugger stepping through your code line by line looking at the variables and flow at each step until your code does something unexpected.

I have no access to the test data

Randomly generate some graphs and compare your output against a similar program (potentially using a library)

Unfortunately this is a problem with most online "competition" or "judge" sites, not providing the data needed to debug your program. Debugging is a very big part of programming, and if you can't debug your program then the provider of the tests might not be a good one.

How can a path be infinitely long and still have an end vertex? Is the program better formulated as "a cycle exists that has an overall negative weight?

On a different note, if values can't be negative then use unsigned integer types. That could catch some problems. And if you have at least some test-data, use compiler sanitizers if available, to help you find problems. And of course, always build with lots of extra warnings enabled, and treated as errors.

Path could be infinitely long and still have an end vertex when it can cycle any number of times (which will increase path length) and then exit the cycle and go to the end node. If there is a path, which enters a cycle, but cannot access end node, than it should not be counted

IMO main problem is main. You have placed o much stuff in main. If you extract proper function then it can be reused ad fed into an automated tests.

There are not much stuff to reuse or call multiple times in this code. This is competitive programming task, so in this and similar tasks I write functions only if I need to use the same code few times (like function check something) or use recursion

"Also I have no access to the test cases" -- Not even the cases you used to test your code? Did you try to cover all the edge and corner cases?

I have only one provided test case:
"
Input:
2 2
1 2 5
1 2 -5
Output:
5
"
I tested some handmade test cases when output should be ":)", ":(" or numeric answer, or when n = 1 or m = 1, and they seem to work. The program actually works, because it passed 21/22 online tests, there must be corner case which I cannot see, because I have no provided tests

I see simple bug:: int val = 0; initial value should be infinitive (something big). Only starting vertex/node should get 0 value.

Marek R i can't just set any initial value, so i use isNull variable to detect was value set before

Your implementation is incomplete.
What you've certainly learned is (for shortest path. Longest is the same with opposite cost), is that Dijkstra algorithm works only with positive weight, while Ford works even when weight might be negative.
So, in your case, just reverse words: Dijkstra works only with all negative weight, while Ford works even if some weight are positive.
But usually, the second part of this sentence is: « if there are no absorbing cycle » (aka negative cycle).
If there is a negative cycle then a longest path doesn't exist. Not because there isn't any path at all. But because there is an infinity of them.
Analogy: the maximum value of a set (max({1,2,3})=3) may not exist for two different reasons:

The set is empty. Since it has no value at all, it has no maximum value: max(ø) doesn't exist)
The set is infinite and has values as big as you want: max(ℕ) doesn't exist neither. Whatever value you may claim is the maximum, there exist a bigger one. If you say 1000000000000000 is the maximum value I can contradict you by saying « then, what about 1000000000000001? »

Same goes here: longest path may not exist for two different reasons

There is no path at all from start to end. So no longest one. You got that covered by testing isNull
There is always a longer path. If there is a cycle with (in your case) positive total weight, then, whatever the path you may claim to be the longest, I can contradict you by saying « then what about the same path, but doing one more loop in that cycle?»

Take this graph

Without cycling longest path is Start→I→End (cost: 20)
Path, going through A cannot be longer. Start→A→B→C→D→End cost 1.
Existence of cycle B→C→D→B isn't a problem. Because it doesn't augment the total weight. Start→A→B→C→D→B→C→D→End cost -1. Start→A→B→C→D→B→C→D→B→C→D→End -3, etc. Each loop in the cycle shorten the path, so, no path is longer than 20 on this side.
But path going through E is another story.
Start→E→F→G→H→End has total weight 5.
But if you loop in the cycle F→G→H→F,
Start→E→F→G→H→F→G→H→End is 8.
Start→E→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→End is 11.
Etc. Each loop in the cycle is a longer path
Start→E→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→End is 23. And beats the longer path. But it is not the longer. And what ever "longer path" you can imagine, I just have to add a F→G→H→ in it to make it even longer
You say   Start→E→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→End
is longest (size 32)?. Well Start→E→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→F→G→H→End
is size 35
Etc.
So, you see the point: there is no longest path, because there is always a longer one. There is no boundary.
You have to detect these situations, to return the information that there is no longest path.
The Bellman-Ford (for shortest path, that you adapted for longest path) is usually
cost(*)=∞ but for cost(Start)=0
For (at least) n-1 times:
    For all edges (A,B):
        If cost(A)+weight(A,B) < cost(B):
            cost(B) = cost(A)+weight(A,B)
            predecessor(B) = A

For all edges(A,B):
    If cost(A)+weight(A,B) < cost(B):
        return "NoShortestPath"

So, algorithm is just n-1 iterations on all edges, checking it an edge can improve a cost, and doing so if it does.
And the last 3 lines, are just a nth iteration. Bellman-Ford says that never more than n-1 iterations are necessary to find shortest path... if it exists (because in a graph with n vertices, a path passing exactly once through each vertex would traverse n-1 edges. So a path of n edges has to pass twice through at least one vertex. So one cycle. So, if that cycle is positive, you could shorten the path by removing the cycle, and that is a path you have already seen before. And if that cycle is negative, then, there isn't any shortest path).
So if a nth iteration would change something, that means that there is no shortest path.
You forgot those 3 lines. That is that nth iteration to check if, after n-1 iterations, it is still possible to improve a cost. If yes, you are in that "no best path exist, because there is always an even better one" situation.
I let you translate that in your C++ (and transpose to "longest path" problem)

You can't decide anything in the nth iteration yet. Worst case, you will need to wait until iteration 2n-1 to decide if a positive cost cycle had existed, as that is the longest possible cycle that could have an effect. Compare the result after 2n-1 cycles with the one after n-1 cycles, and you know for certain if you found an infinite loop.

Thanks for your detailed explanation, but that's exactly what I'm doing in my code. Basically, I first do n-1 iterations that will compute the final value in the case where there are no loops. But after that, for this task in particular, it is not enough for me to do 1 check to detect if the loop exists. I need to do another n-1 check to see if the loop (if it exists) reaches the final node (because the loop may not be connected to the path, then the classical algorithm will indicate the existence of a loop, and I don't have to consider it).

This second step could have been written differently: first find the cycle as you described, then from any vertex of the cycle traverse the widthwise graph and see if the end vertex is encountered during this traversal. Instead, I just run the same algorithm again, checking to see if it changes the final vertex: if so, then the loop can reach the vertex. That outer loop in step 2 was probably redundant

Anyway, there probably is a mistake in the problem tests

So I mark this as an answer
